# The probability for the error correcting code to work

Tags: calculus, probability, binomial-coefficients, coding-theory

Consider a bit (say $0$) duplicate $n$ times in some device:
$$[0]_n = (0,0,\dots, 0).$$
During some procedure, let $p$ be the probability for a bit to change by error. For the error correcting code to work, we need the bit $0$ to be still in a strict majority after the procedure. Here is the probability for that to happen:
$$ P(n,p)= \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lceil n/2 - 1 \right\rceil} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}.$$

**Question:** Is it possible to calculate* this sum in general?

---

*By calculate I mean something like the following examples:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n,$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}=1,$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n p^k = \frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p}.$$

Comment: @MorganRodgers: I mean a computation of the sum in general. It is a calculus question (motivated by error correcting code). So the calculus tag is required. I edited for clarification. Is it clearer?

Comment: The `calculus` tag is for "basic questions about limits, derivatives, integrals, and applications". So I would say that the calculus tag does not belong.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Every sum can be interpreted as an integral (it is sometimes the only known way to calulate it).

Comment: Linking this with [a related oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57186/11619) so that future viewers of the simpler version will find their way here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [precise form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) of the cumulative distribution function of binomial distribution is a bit complicated, but handle-able.  There are some [bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds) you can use.

Depending on your $p$ and $n$, you might be able to get away with [Normal Approximation to the Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) or [De Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).

There are a number of other approximations on Wikipedia as well

Comment: According to the first link you wrote, the integral giving $P(n,p)$ seems to be evaluable.

Comment: For example, in term of the regularized incomplete beta function: $$ P(2n+1,p)=\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2} \int_0^{1-p}(t-t^2)^n dt = \cdots ? $$